# how to get a span cover whole div

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to web scripting. I have to cover up this defect `asap` that's why I am using patches instead of some permanent fix .
I got a defect that a tab get selected only when the lettering of it get selected.

```
<div id='ErrorDictionarySearch_3' onclick='tab_click("0");' class='tab' style='position:absolute;z-index:15;border:none;left:0px;background-color:transparent;width:75px;' >
    <span style='position:absolute;text-align:left;width:100%'>Search</span>
</div>
```

There is an issue with `z-index` but fixing that create some further issues. So I got that the `div` is get selected when span is selected.
So how can I make whole `span` cover that `div`.

**Update** (from comment)

ok i will try to make it more clear to you as you can see there is an onclick event in that div so whenever you should click on that div some thing need to be loaded. but that tab got selected only when mouse cursor is taken over Search ie we can click only when mouse is on lettering

Comment: I have no Idea what you are talking about, but the question in your topic is clear, and you should use div if you want to do that as span is a single line of text that doesn't involve height or you will be making it into something else.

Comment: @CME64 like we can put in a `display: block;` right?

Answer (score 1):

add `display:inline-block;` to the `<span>`

```
<div id='ErrorDictionarySearch_3' onclick='tab_click("0");' class='tab' style='position:absolute;z-index:15;left:0px;background-color:transparent;width:75px;border:1px solid blue;' >
    <span style='text-align:left;width:100%;border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;'>Search</span>
</div>
```

I have added `border:1px solid red;` and `border:1px solid blue;` for reference

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfJFV/

Comment: BTW when I run his code I see that the span's width and div's width are the same!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='ErrorDictionarySearch_3' onclick='tab_click("0");' class='tab' style='position:absolute;z-index:15;border:none;left:0;background-color:transparent;width:75px;' >
    <span style='position:absolute;text-align:left;width:100%;display:block;'>Search</span>
</div>
```

add `display: block` to the `<span>`

Comment: it became no more a span though!